# Use a file between framework

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks

I have two frameworks, one uses the other. I want one of these frameworks to setup the runtime environment for the other, for example it sets the URL of a remote server.

Is it possible for one of my frameworks to use a plist in the other framework to set itself up?

If not are there any alternatives to achieve this effect?